# How to use Tapestry IoC-Services on Websocket-Endpoints events like @OnOpen

Tags: java, websocket, tapestry

In short, i want to know how i can get the message "We have some magic!", when i open a connection to the following websocket endpoint. Obviously, I still lack a little understanding here.

First: The connection is successfully established.

I have a ServerEndpointConfig like this:

```
...

import org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.websocket.HandshakeResponse;
import javax.websocket.server.HandshakeRequest;

public class MyEndpointConfig extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    private MyService1 myService1;

    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
        ServletContext servletContext = httpSession.getServletContext();
        Registry registry = (Registry)servletContext.getAttribute( TapestryFilter.REGISTRY_CONTEXT_NAME );
        myService1 = registry.getService(MyService1.class);
        config.getUserProperties().put("myService1", myService1);
    }

}
```

And there is a great endpoint:

```
...
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value="/myendpoint/", configurator=MyEndpointConfig.class)
public class MyEndpoint {

    private MyService1 myService1;

    @Inject
    private MyService1 myService1_injected;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen( Session session, EndpointConfig config )  throws URISyntaxException {
        Map<String, Object> userProperties = config.getUserProperties();
        myService1 = (MyService1) userProperties.get("myService1");

        Object someMagic = null;
        if(myService1 != null) {
            if(!"<Proxy for myService1(my.package.MyService1)>".equals(myService1.toString())) {
                someMagic = myService1.getSomeMagic();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thats the problem!");
            }
        } else {
            if(myService1_injected != null) {
                someMagic = myService1_injected.getSomeMagic();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thats the problem!");
            }
        }

        if(someMagic != null) System.out.println("We have some magic!");
    }
```

Comment: Hmm...nobody knows? :(

Comment: so, what's the problem? `myService1` should be not null, and `myService1_injected` should be null -- is this what you're experiencing?

Comment: I figured out that the problem is not the service itself, but something he should deliver back. The service should return an object from the org.apache.tapestry5.services.Session via the org.apache.tapestry5.services.Request. That does not work. Hard to say why ...